# How to capture request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

My scenario is：

```
function testb() { b() } // written by me
function b() { 
    sendRequest1(); //eg: http://test1
    sendRequest2(); //eg: http://test2

} // a third party library, it is black box for me
```

My question is when calling testb(), is there one way to capture/get urls of request1 and request2? I would like to do some checks, eg: the query string is correct.
Some web proxy tools(eg: Charles) would help to do this. But I want to do it in JavaScript. Is it possible?

This is just a test case for test b(). Because there are many similar cases for b(). So automated cases could be helpful for me.

Comment: If it's "black box" for you, consider what it is for us who don't even have the code to look at ?

Comment: Why do oyu need to do it with JS? why not jsut take a look in Firebug or with something like Charles? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Updated the description for the question

Comment: @adeneo a "black box" can still have observable side effects - the OP wants to observe those.

Answer (score 3):

On some browsers at least (I've tried this in Chrome) you can "monkey patch" the `XMLHttpRequest` object, e.g.:

```
(function(xhr) {
    var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    xhr.prototype.open = function() {
       console.log(arguments);
       open.apply(this, arguments);
    };

})(XMLHttpRequest);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/tbdNJ/